# XQuery - to insert splitted nodes data into another node

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <A><DelInfo>123-20150308-345</DelInfo><OrderNo>11</OrderNo></A>
  <A><DelInfo>1204-20150308-355</DelInfo><OrderNo>15</OrderNo></A>
  <A><DelInfo>153-20150408-343</DelInfo><OrderNo>10</OrderNo></A>
  <A><DelInfo>44345-20150308-341</DelInfo><OrderNo>21</OrderNo></A>
  <A><DelInfo>153-20150204-245</DelInfo><OrderNo>1</OrderNo></A>
  <A><DelInfo>423-20150311-445</DelInfo><OrderNo>13</OrderNo></A>
  ..........
</Data>
```

I receive following XML. The `DelInfo` node contains a combination of
EmpId, Delivery Date and Receipt No. The `OrderNo` node contains the
order number wrt the Delivery Information.

The XML is stored in BaseX and I need following report to be generated from the 
above XML.

```
<A><DelInfo>123-20150308-345</DelInfo><OrderNo>11</OrderNo><Report>20150308 - 11</Report></A>
.....
```

In other word, I want to insert an additional node `Report` with Date and Order No.
Any idea?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am little confused on how to get the date part!!

Comment: You need to use `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` functions to extract the `Date` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `yourdoc` with your document name.

```
for $x in doc('yourdoc')//A
  let $d := substring-before(substring-after($x/DelInfo, "-"), "-")
  let $o := $x/OrderNo/text()
  let $i := <C>{concat($d, " - ", $o)}</C>
return 
    insert node $i after $x/OrderNo
```

The inner `substring-after()` will return the string after the first `-`. Then, the `substring-before()` will return the string before the `-`. This way you will get the Date portion.